# How to set SRID of the geometry attribute of GeoServer layer (automatically or through code), instead of -1 default value

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, geoserver, ogr2ogr, srid

Because of my [problem with spatial queries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/449678/geoserver-returns-error-when-using-cql-filter-intersects-st-intersects-op/449777#449777) (INTERSECTS) not working properly on a layer with SRID = -1 created with ogr2ogr - I need to force SRID of the geometry attribute of the layer to be automatically guesed or set it through the code during or after the layer creation process:

[image: SRID -1(minus one)]

SQL View of the table:

```
SELECT * FROM "e2b0ad81_8888_4cd4_b455_6060e4cbea3e"
```

When I do "Guess geometry type and srid" here (GeoServer admin panel) - it guesses SRID right, ao I think it could be done automatically somehow

---

I found a messed up way around the problem:

Turned out that config that specifies the SRID field lays not in the DB but inside GeoServer container itself - somwhere like:

`/opt/services/storage/%BD name?%/geoserver/data_dir/workspaces/%BD user?%/database/%LAYER NAME%/featuretype.xml`

And after adding/modifiyng (top lavel) this to the XML file:

```
<geometry>
    <name>the_geom</name>
    <type>Geometry</type>
    <srid>3857</srid>
</geometry>
```

And **after restarting container** with GeoServer - the changes aplayes and spatial queries work

---

Is there any better way to do this?

Preferably without restarting anything

---

Layer ogr2ogr command:

`ogr2ogr -progress -overwrite -nln e2b0ad81_8888_4cd4_b455_6060e4cbea3e -t_srs EPSG:3857 -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom -lco FID=fid -dialect OGRSQL -sql "%ATTRS CREATION SQL% string" -s_srs EPSG:3857 PG:host=%HOST% port=%PORT% user=%USER% dbname=%DBNAME% password=%PW% 'sridtest.gpkg'`

Geometry attribute SQL creation line:

`the_geom geometry(Point,3857),`

Full layer table SQL creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."e2b0ad81_8888_4cd4_b455_6060e4cbea3e"
(
    fid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"e2b0ad81_8888_4cd4_b455_6060e4cbea3e_fid_seq"'::regclass),
    attr_0 character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    ...
    attr_21 character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    
    the_geom geometry(Point,3857),
    
    CONSTRAINT "e2b0ad81_8888_4cd4_b455_6060e4cbea3e_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (fid)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."e2b0ad81_8888_4cd4_b455_6060e4cbea3e"
    OWNER to mapuser;

REVOKE ALL ON TABLE public."e2b0ad81_8888_4cd4_b455_6060e4cbea3e" FROM replicator;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE public."e2b0ad81_8888_4cd4_b455_6060e4cbea3e" TO mapuser;

GRANT SELECT ON TABLE public."e2b0ad81_8888_4cd4_b455_6060e4cbea3e" TO replicator;
-- Index: e2b0ad81_8888_4cd4_b455_6060e4cbea3e_geom_geom_idx

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public."e2b0ad81_8888_4cd4_b455_6060e4cbea3e_geom_geom_idx";

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "e2b0ad81_8888_4cd4_b455_6060e4cbea3e_geom_geom_idx"
    ON public."e2b0ad81_8888_4cd4_b455_6060e4cbea3e" USING gist
    (the_geom)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Versions:

```
GeoServer 2.17.2 
GeoTools 23.2 (rev 3a74d70c88a384047c14ebcb77420d0bd0ba0fc2) 
GeoWebCache 1.17.2 (rev 1.17.x/b5344b575976fe578594157fb9a90cb399f8b272)
```

Comment: is this an SQL View? as there should be no need to "guess" the SRID of a well constructed table.

Comment: @IanTurton, the screenshot is SQL View, yes.

How can I fix the way my table is constructed to make it work well?

Comment: Then we need to see the SQL you are using, the table is irrelevant and can be removed from the question.

Comment: @IanTurton, I added SQL View of the table. I think the table itself may help someone with the similar problem to understand what I'm talking about by visual reference.

Comment: I suspect that your view is not being picked up in the geometry_columns view so GeoServer can't tell what the type and srid of the geometry is. I'm not sure if the CTE is what's fooling it, can you try without it

Comment: @IanTurton, I tried to create new layer with view like this - the same -1 in geometry SRID: SELECT * FROM "86d17050_a9fb_4d25_8c9c_ea35aef9d138"